# How do I make sbt run a task only once even though it is indirectly specified multiple times on the cli?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

Here is my plugin code. It defines a master `lint` task that is triggered from the CLI like so: `sbt api/lint jobs/lint`. It calls out to some project-specific linters and some build-wide linters. The build-wide linter runs scalafix, but if I call `lint` multiple times from the CLI, as above (for multiple projects), then scalafix is run multiple times.

How do I make scalafix (and `scalafixLinter`) run only one time for a given `sbt` invocation? I thought sbt caches task results, but it seems to not be working here.

```
object LinterPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {
    lazy val scalafixLinter = taskKey[Unit]("Run scalafix on all scala code")
    lazy val lint = taskKey[Unit]("Run all linters")
  }

  override val buildSettings = Seq(
    scalafixLinter := {
      Def.taskDyn {
        if (...) {
          Def.task {
            // run scalafix
            (Compile / scalafix).toTask("").value
            (Test / scalafix).toTask("").value
          }
        } else {
          Def.task {}
        }
      }.all(ScopeFilter(inAnyProject)).value // run on all projects
    }
  )

  override val projectSettings = Seq(
    lint := {
      // run all the linters
      otherLinters.value
      scalafixLinter.value
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FileFunction.cache method. Though that only works for files.